# How to prove a function from a set of triples to $\mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{N}_7)$ is a bijection?

Tags: functions, proof-writing, proof-verification

Let $Y=\{y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4,y_5\}$

The function from the set of triples $(y_{i_1},y_{i_2},y_{i_3})$ where $i_1 \le i_2 \le i_3$ to $\mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{N}_7)$ is a bijection given by $(y_{i_1},y_{i_2},y_{i_3})\mapsto \{i_1,i_2+1,i_3+2\}$.

How do I prove that the above function is a bijection?

My attempt:

---

Let $h$ denote the given function.

---

**$h$ is injective**

$\begin{align}
h((y_a,y_b,y_c))=h((y_d,y_e,y_f)) & \Rightarrow & \{a,b+1,c+2\} = \{ d,e+1,f+2\}
\end{align}$

Furthermore:

$\begin{align}
a\le b \le c \text{ and } d\le e \le f & \Rightarrow & a\le b < b+1 \le c < c+3 \text{ and } d \le e < e+1 \le f < f+2\\
& \Rightarrow & a < b+1 < c + 2 \text{ and } d<e+1<f+2
\end{align}$

This means that the elements in the set $ \{a,b+1,c+2\}$ and $\{ d,e+1,f+2\} $ are already arranged in ascending order. Therefore, given that the two sets are equal, $a=d,b=e,c=f$ so that $(y_a,y_b,y_c)=(y_d,y_e,y_f)$ as required.

Is this an acceptable way to prove that $h$ is injective?

---

**$h$ is surjective**

Let $A = \{a_1,a_2,a_3\}\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}_7)$.

Since, the domain of $h$ has the condition $i_1 \le i_2 \le i_3$, I thought it might help to also impose the condition $a_1<a_2<a_3$ to the elements in $A$.

How do I argue that there exists an element in the domain of $h$, say $x$, such that $h(x)=A$?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, does $\mathbb{N}_7$ has a canonical meaning?

Comment: $\mathbb{N}_7$ means $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$

Comment: You're asking how to prove that a certain function is a bijection, but I don't see a definition of your function.

Comment: @Frunobulax Sorry, didn't realize that. I've updated my question.

Comment: I don't think this will be bijective, for instance consider $\{1,2,3,4\}$. This is certainly an element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})_7$ but cannot be in the image of $h$.

Comment: @DanZimm Sorry, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})_7$ is actually $\mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{N}_7)$

Comment: @mauna does this mean the set of all possible subsets of $\mathbb{N}_7$ with $3$ elements?

Comment: @DanZimm Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3\} \in \mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{N}_7)$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{N}_7$ and w.l.o.g. consider $a_1 < a_2 < a_3$.

Now we want to find $i_1,i_2,i_3$ so that $(y_{i_1}, y_{i_2}, y_{i_3})$ maps to $A$.

I'm going to give you a hint for finding $i_2$ and then hopefully you see what to do for $i_1$ and $i_3$:

Note that $a_2 > 1$ (why?) and put $i_2 = a_2 - 1$. Do you see why this will work?

Comment: $a_2>1$ because if $a_2\le 1$, this implies $a_1\notin \mathbb{N}_7$ which contradicts the assumption $a_i\in \mathbb{N}_7$. So, $a_2 > 1 \Rightarrow i_2=a_2-1>0$, $a_2<a_3\Rightarrow i_3 = a_3-2 \le 5$ and let $i_1=a_1$. Therefore, $a_1<a_2<a_3 \Rightarrow 1 \le a_1 \le a_2-1\le a_3-2\le 5\Rightarrow 1 \le i_1 \le i_2 \le i_3 \le 5 \text{ and } i_1,i_2,i_3\in \mathbb{N}_5$. So, we can find $i_1,i_2,i_3$ so that $(y_{i_1}, y_{i_2}, y_{i_3})$ maps to $A$. Hence, $h$ is surjective.Is this correct and can I have some help on proving $h$ is injective?